# Using reserved word "action" as an MVC parameter name

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

To provide details regarding my platform. I am using Visual Studio 2017 with a .NET Core Web project.

I am implementing a new back-end for a client for which I cannot alter the client. I am attempting to use MVC to accomplish this.

The URL which I must be able to respond to is -> https://my.server.com:8443/portal/gateway?sessionId=0A6405100000001D04FB55FE&portal=4ba457d0-e371-11e6-92ce-005056873bd0&action=cwa&token=3fcbc246bb3c35a5fa8055fec6bbf431

I would like to extract the values for :

- sessionId
- portal
- action
- token

As they all have meaning.

I have created a new view folder within my project called "Portal" and have created a new MVC controller named "PortalController".

I have created a new View called gateway.cshtml and also have implemented the following function ->

```
public IActionResult Gateway(string sessionId, string portal, string action, string token)
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Gateway";
    return View();
}
```

When I set a breakpoint within the function, I receive the following values for the URL provided above ->

```
    sessionId   "0A6405100000001D04FB55FE"              string
    portal      "4ba457d0-e371-11e6-92ce-005056873bd0"  string
    action      "gateway"                               string
    token       "3fcbc246bb3c35a5fa8055fec6bbf431"      string
```

As can be seen in the output of the debugger, for the parameter named "action", isntead of receiving the value "cwa" as passed by the client, I instead receive the name "gateway" which is passed by MVC as the name of the action.

Is there a "proper way" of handling this?

I would prefer to avoid altering the routes within the startup.cs file as this hurts the modularity of the code. I would welcome attributes that could be used to reroute the parameter names.

Another alternative I could see (buy can't figure out) is to simply make use of the HTTP request to read the values I'm interested in instead of using function parameters.

Thank you very much in advance for any assistance you can provide!

Comment: I suspect that if the routes in startup.cs rely on "action" meaning Action then that die is cast and you won't be able to have a RouteValue parameter of the same name: duplicate key in RouteValueDictionary. Modifying startup.cs doesn't sound bad –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .Net Core you can get your `action` parameter value straight off the `Request` with

```
var action= Request.Query["action"];
```

where in .Net Framework it was

```
var action= Request.QueryString["action"];
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I knew that existed but couldn't find reference to anything but QueryString[] and I assumed that it was a .NET Core-ism...

Answer (score 0):

You can also pull the value using [`[FromQuery]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromqueryattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.2) like this

```cs
public IActionResult Gateway([FromQuery]string action)
{
    return Json(new { action });
}
```

This works since you are passing via a query param in a url structured like this:

`https://my.server.com:8443/portal/gateway?action=cwa`

Although, I'd caution that this still uses [**Reserved Keywords in MVC**](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/wiki/MVC-Reserved-Keywords) which can cause unpredictable behavior.  As long as you can control the url, it's safer to just *rename the parameter* with a more detailed name like this:

```cs
public IActionResult Gateway(string userAction)
{
    return Json(new { userAction});
}
```